# How can I capture process names using the TraceEvent library?

Tags: c#, .net, etw, etw-eventsource

I'm using the [TraceEvent library](https://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TraceEvent) to capture ETW traces, but I'm not able to determine the name of the process that caused an event.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var session = new TraceEventSession(sessionName, null);
session.EnableProvider(MyEventSource.Log.Guid, TraceEventLevel.Informational,
    options: TraceEventOptions.Stacks);
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => session.Stop()); // for testing, deal with it (⌐■_■)
var src = new ETWTraceEventSource(sessionName, TraceEventSourceType.Session);
TraceLog.CreateFromSource(src, etlxFile, null);
var log = TraceLog.OpenOrConvert(etlxFile);
var process = log.Events.First().ProcessName;
// breakpoint
```

When the breakpoint at the end is hit, `process` is `""`. `ProcessID` is a proper PID, but that's the only useful information I could find from the processes in the log.

I expected process names to be captured by the log. Am I doing something wrong, or is this API just not available on my OS (Windows 7)?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2013/03/09/using-traceevent-to-mine-information-in-os-registered-etw-providers.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I truly believe that process name is not being captured by the ETW log. Etw system event contains only process ID field. Although TraceEvent library declares this one as a part of TraceEvent, this one actually is being populated based on executable image filename and process ID, which is implemented differently for all 4 TraceEventSource implementations.

Another observation is that I was never able to have this one populated (my OS is Windows 8.1).

The simple repro is to use SimpleEventSourceMonitor sample from [Microsoft TraceEvent Library Samples](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent.Samples/) package.

If you suspect that this is an issue, then it is better ask its owners Vance Morrison and Cosmin Radu.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by enabling the kernel provider, and then maintaining a lookup of process id to process name.  Here's a rough example - no error checking, but you get the idea.

```
// create a lookup collection for future use    
var pidToProcessName = new Dictionary<int, string>();

var session = new TraceEventSession(...);
// enable the kernel provider - note!  this most come first
session.EnableKernelProvider(KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.Process);
...
session.Source.Kernel.ProcessStart += ProcessStart;
session.Source.Dynamic.All += TraceEvent;
...
session.Source.Procces();    


void ProcessStart(ProcessTraceData obj)
{
    if(obj.OpCode == TraceEventOpcode.Start)
    {
        pidToProcessName[obj.ProcessID] = obj.ProcessName;
    }
}

void TraceEvent(TraceEvent obj)
{
    // pull the process name from our lookup
    var processNameOfEvent = pidToProcessName[obj.ProcessID];    
}
```